# java + version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]

Tags: linux, java, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am running the following application on my Linux machine
and we get the:

version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]

**important remark - we not have the file - pom.xml in my OS!!!**

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /opt/mcspace/evenacer/mc.kafka.debug.eventTracer.jar server /opt/mcce/evencer/appation.yml

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 45005


SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
```

what is the meaning about version 1.7.16 - it it mean the version of the jar file ???

what is 1.6 version?

my java version on my linux machine:

```
# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: All explained here: https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch basically the versions of your slf4j jars aren't the same.

Comment: yes but this not answer on my question

Comment: The two versions mentioned are the versions of slf4j-api.jar and the other slf4j jar you have (slf4j-jdk*.jar, slf4j-log4j*.jar...)